# C# compiler on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

If I use a third party C# compiler to compile code written with notepad can I make a Windows Phone 7 app or do I have to use Microsoft's IDE?

Comment: I think will be better to use Microsoft IDE and platform

Comment: I've used MS Build directly, no Visual Studio. So **no** is the answer to "do I have to use the IDE?".

Comment: The IDE is free, why would you not want to use it?

Comment: Why not just get a free version of Visual Studio? http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-Phone

Comment: Yes I agree you can download the VS Express Edition, it's allow you to build basic applicaions

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question directly, *no*, you do not have to use Visual Studio.

To elaborate further.. You can use the compilers directly (csc etc) but it's more complex and completely pointless. The whole point of Windows Phone development that they keep advertising is that the whole toolchain is free, from VS Express up to Expression Blend for UI creation.

I don't see any reason why you wouldn't want to use these tools, writing code in Notepad (although more challenging and rewarding!) is a lot slower, prone to errors, and simply pointless when you have a perfectly good toolset at your disposal for no price.

See the following:

- Visual C# Express - http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CS
- Expression Blend (included as part of the WP SDK) - http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/7/7/177D6AF8-17FA-40E7-AB53-00B7CED31729/vm_web.exe
- WP getting started guide - http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/getting_started